# changing key values of all elements in a multimap container

Tags: c++, multimap

I am working on a c++ code which includes a command schedule. I implement the schedule as a multimap container, with execution time,as the key, and command name I want to execute. I need to be able to time shift all the commands in the schedule.

I assume I can do that by copying the container to another container and erasing the original container, then changing the key values for each pair in the copy container and inserting it back in the original container, like the example code below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <map>

  int main() {
    std::multimap<int,int> original,copy;
    original.insert(std::pair<int,int>(10,1));
    original.insert(std::pair<int,int>(10,2));
    original.insert(std::pair<int,int>(12,3));
    std::multimap<int,int>::iterator it;
    copy=original;
    it=original.begin();
    original.erase(it,original.end());
    int tctime;
    int command;
    for (it=copy.begin();it!=copy.end();it++){
        tctime =(*it).first+5;
        command=(*it).second;
        original.insert(std::pair<int,int> (tctime, command));
    }
    return 0;
  }
```

while this works, I would like to know if there is a better solution to implement it.

Comment: If you want review or tips on improving already working code, try [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Although you should ask these kind of questions on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), I will write my answer here also so it may help someone else (and since it is not yet closed).

First, since your question has a C++ tag, please use `#include <iostream>` instead of `#include <stdio.h>`.

Second, I suggest you to use `std::make_pair` instead of the `std::pair` constructor. `std::make_pair` automatically deduces types of the values passed to it so I would prefer it over `std::pair` where you need to specify the types. So, you should use something like this:

```cpp
original.insert(std::make_pair(10,1));
```

Next, since you are erasing all the values from the `std::multimap<int,int> original`, why not just use `std::multimap::clear`? It is less code to write and your intention is more straightforward.

```cpp
original.clear()
```

instead of

```cpp
it=original.begin();
original.erase(it,original.end());
```

Furthermore, I would suggest using range-for loops over the standard loops.

```cpp
for (auto const& it : copy) {
    tctime = it.first +5;
    command = it.second;
    original.insert(std::make_pair(tctime, command));
}
```

instead of

```cpp
for (auto it = copy.begin(); it != copy.end(); it++){
    tctime =(*it).first+5;
    command=(*it).second;
    original.insert(std::pair<int,int>(tctime, command));
}
```

And the last thing, good practice would be to initialize variables `tctime` and `command` to 0.

Full code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main() {
    std::multimap<int,int> original,copy;
    original.insert(std::make_pair(10,1));
    original.insert(std::make_pair(10,2));
    original.insert(std::make_pair(12,3));

    copy=original;
    original.clear();

    int tctime = 0;
    int command = 0;

    for (auto const& it : copy) {
        tctime = it.first +5;
        command = it.second;
        original.insert(std::make_pair(tctime, command));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[Here](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:43,endLineNumber:8,positionColumn:43,positionLineNumber:8,selectionStartColumn:43,selectionStartLineNumber:8,startColumn:43,startLineNumber:8),source:'%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Cmap%3E%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++std::multimap%3Cint,int%3E+original,copy%3B%0A++++original.insert(std::make_pair(10,1))%3B%0A++++original.insert(std::make_pair(10,2))%3B%0A++++original.insert(std::make_pair(12,3))%3B%0A%0A++++copy%3Doriginal%3B%0A++++original.clear()%3B%0A%0A++++int+tctime+%3D+0%3B%0A++++int+command+%3D+0%3B%0A%0A++++for+(auto+const%26+it+:+copy)+%7B%0A++++++++tctime+%3D+it.first+%2B5%3B%0A++++++++command+%3D+it.second%3B%0A++++++++original.insert(std::make_pair(tctime,+command))%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:54.308093994778076,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g92,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'0',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B14+-O3',selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+9.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:45.97651026222455,l:'4',m:51.042810098792536,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+gcc+9.2',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:48.957189901207464,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:45.691906005221924,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4) is the fully refactored code live.

Comment: Thanks alot! It really helped to improve the code! thanks for answering before it was closed.

Comment: @Ma Ta I believe you can accept the answer (by clicking the tick next to it) if it helped you